# How to create pair RDD with elements that share keys in source RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have a key-value RDD in pyspark and would like to return an RDD of pairs that have the same key in the source RDD.

```
#input rdd of id and user
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(1, "user1"), (1, "user2"), (2, "user1"), (2, "user3"), (3,"user2"), (3,"user4"), (3,"user1")])

#desired output
[("user1","user2"),("user1","user3"),("user1","user4"),("user2","user4")]
```

So far I have been unable to come up with the correct combination of functions to do this. The purpose of this is to create an edge list of users based off of a shared common key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your description something like this should work:

```
output = (rdd1
   .groupByKey()
   .mapValues(set)
   .flatMap(lambda kvs: [(x, y) for x in kvs[1] for y in kvs[1] if x < y])
   .distinct())
```

Unfortunately it is rather expensive operation.

Comment: I think you can try aggregateByKey() and implement some of your own logic to get slightly better performance than groupByKey(). That will first combine on the partition side before the final merge.

Comment: @ChrisChambers Nothing in the example input suggests there are duplicates values per key so `mapValues(set)` is just a precaution. Otherwise it would be of course worth trying.